# What does the IEEE 754 single precision representation of the number 0 look like?

Tags: ieee-754

I tried to type this into all online converters, but the answer **0 00000000 00000000000000000000000** is not helpful.

I tried the String **0 01111111 00000000000000000000000** as an answer, the exponent (with bias) in denary is 0. And my final equation is **0.0 * 2^0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“0 00000000 00000000000000000000000” is the answer. The IEEE-754 binary32 representation of zero has all bits zero.

IEEE-754 does distinguish a +0 and a −0. The above is +0. For −0, flip the first bit, “1 00000000 00000000000000000000000”.